# Is there a reason that our product catalog is pulling the wrong images for some products but not others?

Tags: facebook-ads-api

Our business manager is set up to sell our products: Wheels, Tires, and Suspension Components for Cars and Trucks.

We are running into an issue in our product catalog from which our dynamic ads pulls from: **Wheels and Suspension component product photos are pulled correctly and show the proper image for said product, but the tires we have listed on our websites do not pull the correct photos, and instead show a placeholder logo image **

Please let me know the necessary steps to resolve this issue.

Comment: There's no hope of an answer without seeing some code.

Comment: I have a clean and precise answer for your: Your code has a bug! Please find it (we can't)